# Connect to a Kepware KepServerEx V6 that runs on Windows using python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.6, opc-ua

I'm new to this Kepware KEPServerEX V6 thing that I run in Windows 11 locally. Now, I am creating a client via  python-opcua package from https://github.com/FreeOpcUa to connect to it but had a connection refused issue. Can anyone help me. And what are the things I need to setup in-order to establish a successful connection from my client to the KEPServerEX.

Here's a litte snippet:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
from opcua import Client

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49320")

    try:
        client.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Here the error result:
**[Errno 111] Connection refused**

I tried searching on google and youtube.com but I couldn't find any resources that is related to my issue.

Comment: Did you try to start a connection, with a gui client, like UAExpert? Also keep in mind python opcua is no longer supported, best to get startet with https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio. asnycio also has a sync layer, if you don't want to deal with asyncio.

Comment: Hi @Schroeder, in Windows, I have no problem connecting to the KepServerEx. But i'm connecting to it via wsl in Windows.

Comment: WSL is the error here, you have to figure out the windows (host) ipaddress, which is not 127.0.0.1 !